# war file deployment through weblogic

Tags: weblogic, war

While deploying war file using weblogic-10.3.6 I am getting the exceptions like

*** The error is weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorException: VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND
problem: cvc-enumeration-valid: string value '3.0' is not a valid enumeration value for web-app-versionType in namespace http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee:***

Can anyone tell me what is the problem ?

Answer (score 7):

Normally this problem indicates there is an issue with your weblogic/WSDL header information. In this case:

- **Weblogic 10.3.6. does not support servlet spec 3**

Upgrade to 12c or choose a different version of the spec in your code/WSDL/etc

Specifically switch from something like:

```
<web-app version="3.0" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
```

to:

```
<web-app version="2.5" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```